# Random in a Int[]

Tags: java, random, minecraft, bukkit, items

I want to the player receive a random item in the Int[]

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {


Player player = (Player) sender;

if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("surprise")){
Random random = new Random();

PlayerInventory inventory = player.getInventory();
int ItensIds[] = {274, 313, 314, 315, 316};
ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.AIR);



for(int Ids : ItensIds){

    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(300);
    do{
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(300);
        item.setTypeId(Ids);
        inventory.addItem(item);
    } while(randomNumber == Ids);

    break;
}

}
```

Im trying to figure how it works but ends crashing the server or not working at all.

Im really new at this code stuff, please understand if I did something really wrong.

Comment: when it crashes what is the exception ? why are you generating  random number twice ? what is the point of `for` loop since you are breaking it anyways after first iteration

Comment: What is the point of `do{ ... } while(randomNumber == Ids);`?

Comment: I don't now much of coding, if i did something really wrong please fix for me

Comment: What are you attempting to do in the for-loop? Avoid a random number equal to `Ids`?

Comment: Please provide a stack trace.  Don't make us all guess what the error is.

Comment: so which part of your code you want to _get random item in the Int[]_??

Comment: @BlackDereker - What do you mean by this "I want to the player receive a random item in the Int[]". Do you mean inside ItensIds[] ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to the player receive one of the itens in the ItensIds[] but randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I want to the player receive a random item in the Int[]"*

If you want to get random value from your `int` array (which is `ItensIds[]`), you can just do this:

```
int randomNumber = ItensIds[random.nextInt(ItensIds.length)];
```

You don't need loop or whatsoever.